# Building just Firefox for Tor Browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox, build

I am actually working on modifying some parts of Tor Browser for my project and for that I will need to build Tor Browser's source code. I was following [this website](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorBrowser/Hacking) and after cloning tor-browser-build repo, I did a `make nightly-linux-x86_64`, which took almost half a day to complete on my Ubuntu 18.04 system. But, since I would be making some changes to the browser (mostly Firefox code), I need to alter code and build multiple times.

In the above website, there is an option for '*Building Just Firefox*' and I decided to try that. As per the above website/doc, I cloned tor-browser repo and followed the instructions. First, the command

```
make $CONFIGURE_ARGS -f client.mk configure CONFIGURE_ARGS="--with-tor-browser-version=tbb-nightly --with-distribution-id=org.torproject --enable-update-channel=default --enable-bundled-fonts"
```

gave me :

> client.mk:40: /.mozconfig-client-mk: No such file or directory
>
> client.mk:72: *** client.mk must be used via `mach`. Try running
> `./mach configure`.  Stop.

`./mach configure` was not working as well, but using [this webpage](https://hg.mozilla.org/integration/autoland/rev/36f4ba2fb6f5), I patched the *init.configure* file and it worked. But now when I run `./mach build`, it finally gives (after doing a lot of compilation):

[image: Error]

So could anyone please guide me as to how should I go about doing this. Basically as I had said in the beginning, I just want to modify and rebuild to test the new code that I would be introducing. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it with the help of the Tor developers (they are really nice!).

So, as can be seen, the [wiki](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorBrowser/Hacking) has been updated now and the commands altered a bit. One needs to clone the appropriate branch and not just blindly do a `git clone https://git.torproject.org/tor-browser.git`, because this clones the master branch. Use the `-b` flag to clone a specific branch, say `tor-browser-60.7.0esr-9.0-1` (latest at the time of writing this answer). Now all you need to do is :

1. `git clone https://git.torproject.org/tor-launcher.git`
2. `mv tor-launcher browser/extensions/`
3. ```
   ./mach configure --with-tor-browser-version=tbb-nightly --with-distribution-id=org.torproject --enable-update-channel=default --enable-bundled-fonts
   ```

   If you don't have the packages, just do a `./mach bootstrap`
4. `./mach build`
5. `./mach build stage-package`
6. `cp -a obj-*/dist/firefox/* path_to_tor_browser_directory/Browser/`

There is one issue that I was facing though. I had the latest rust version, which was 1.35.0 and it won't build (would give me some macro related errors). I had to downgrade rust to v1.29.1 and it worked.